# Having an error "MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given." while generating migration with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I'm trying to generate migrations. I have added these lines to package.json

```
 "typeorm": "node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js  --config src/config/configuration.ts",
 "migration:generate":"npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n"
```

I have a configuration.ts file instead of ormconfig.json which looks like this.

```
import { join } from 'path';

export default () => {
  const host = process.env.DB_HOST;
  const port = process.env.DB_PORT;
  const username = process.env.DB_USERNAME;
  const password = process.env.DB_PASSWORD;
  const database = process.env.DB_DATABASE;

  return {
    database: {
      type: 'mariadb',
      host,
      port,
      username,
      password,
      database,
      entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
      synchronize: false,
      migrations: ['/src/migration/**/*.ts'],
      keepConnectionAlive: true,
      charset: 'utf8mb4',
      cli: {
        migrationsDir: '/src/migrations',
      },
    },
  };
};
```

while running the command

```
npm run migration:generate -- softDeleteUser
```

having this error

```
> user-service@0.0.1 migration:generate
> npm run typeorm migration:generate -- -n "softDeleteUser"


> user-service@0.0.1 typeorm
> node --require ts-node/register ./node_modules/typeorm/cli.js  --config src/config/configuration.ts "migration:generate" "-n" "softDeleteUser"

Error during migration generation:
MissingDriverError: Wrong driver: "undefined" given. Supported drivers are: "cordova", "expo", "mariadb", "mongodb", "mssql", "mysql", "oracle", "postgres", "sqlite", "better-sqlite3", "sqljs", "react-native", "aurora-data-api", "aurora-data-api-pg".
at new MissingDriverError (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/src/error/MissingDriverError.ts:8:9)
    at DriverFactory.create (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/src/driver/DriverFactory.ts:67:23)
    at new Connection (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/src/connection/Connection.ts:128:43)
    at ConnectionManager.create (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/src/connection/ConnectionManager.ts:64:28)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/src/index.ts:230:35)
    at step (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:141:27)
    at Object.next (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:122:57)
    at /Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:115:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (/Users/akash/Documents/Projects/pulp-backend/user-service/node_modules/tslib/tslib.js:111:16)
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to export config like :

```
export = ORMConfig;
```

Comment: Yes, didn't work. I had to use ormconfig file

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same error, so I tried to do what the docs say. I imported my database config inside app.module imports like so:

```
`import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule } from '@nestjs/typeorm';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRoot({
      type: 'mysql',
      host: 'localhost',
      port: 3306,
      username: 'root',
      password: 'root',
      database: 'test',
      entities: [],
      synchronize: true,
    }),
  ],
})
```

but unfortunately it wasn't a cause.
The real cause was in my entity file, where I put columns in the entity table.
I had:

```
    @Column({
    type: 'float',
    precision: 6,
    scale: 2,
  })
  price: number;
```

instead of:

```
    @Column({
    type: 'decimal',
    precision: 6,
    scale: 2,
  })
  price: number;
```

because only decimals take precision and scale properties
All variants are described there: https://typeorm.io/entities#column-options

Comment: For me I had to use a ormconfig file

Answer (score 0):

The below solution works in my case.

File `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
    ConfigModule.forRoot({isGlobal: true}),
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
        useClass: DatabaseConnectionService //DatabaseConnectionService is 
        //the  file containing the connection code
    }) ,
    UserModule
]
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).